# Laravel undefined variable when trying to pass data to view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to pass data from my controller to my view, but am getting an undefined variable error. usersID is a column in my MySQL table.

Here is the code in my controller

```
$arrayWithCount = DB :: table("users_has_activities")
-> where("usersID", "=", 19)
-> pluck("usersID");

$countNumber = sizeof($arrayWithCount);

return view('pages.progress', ['countNumber' => $countNumber]);
```

I have also tried the following return statement without any success

```
return view::make('pages.progress') -> with('countNumber', $countNumber);
```

I have also tried reversing the puck and where clauses without any success, I didn't have high hopes that reversing them would fix the problem but thought I would try it any way. Below is the  relevant code in the blade file.

```
 <?php echo $countNumber; ?>
```

This is the error I am currently getting

```
Undefined variable: countNumber
```

Comment: Try to `dd($countNumber);` before `return view` clause. What does it show?

Comment: I added a dd($countNumber); statement in my controller before I return the view but I still get the same error. Is there a special place I need to go to where I can see the result of dd($countNumber); ?

Comment: Are you sure you're executing right method? Because `dd()` should display something and stop execution. Double check your routes and controllers.

Comment: You were right I had all the controller code in a method I wasn't calling, so the variable was never passed to the blade file. The method was set up to be called on a button press, after fixing that everything works. Thanks for your help

Comment: glad I was able to help. Please choose my answer as best one and upvote if you want to thank me for my time. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks fine, if `dd()` doesn't stop execution of the controller, then another controller is executing. So double check your routes and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

First `sizeof` should be `sizeOf`, and is simply an alias for `count()`. Most people would prefer `count` over `sizeOf` as sizeOf (in many languages) would indicate something related to size on disk.

Anywho, being that pluck returns a collection, you have access to `count()` directly from the collection.

You can probably simply do something like:

```
$countNumber = $arrayWithCount->count();
```

**Sidenote:** Unless there is a particular reason why you are using `<?php ?>`, in blade, it would be preferred to use `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: I tried using count() before but changed it to sizeOf() hoping it would fix the errors it did not. I corrected sizeOf() and also tried using $countNumber = $arrayWithCount->count(); but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had all the controller code in a method I wasn't calling, so the variable was never passed to the blade file. The method was set up to be called on a button press, after fixing that everything works. Thanks Alexey for the help.